# How to make checkboxes in a list view control tri-state?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Is it possible to make the checkboxes in a list view control with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES style tri-state (having BS_3STATE button style)? I'm using WTL but I'm OK manually sending messages around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need an ImageList with 3 images of a unchecked, checked and indeterminate checkbox.  Call ListView_SetImageList() to assign the LVSIL_STATE image list.  Manipulate LVITEM.state to display the kind of checkbox you want.

Comment: Interesting solution, much easier than making the list owner draw and drawing the items myself that I was thinking about. But since MFC's CCheckListBox class has a SetCheckStyle() method that does exactly what I want I was hoping to find a simple solution like that outside MFC.

Comment: I couldn't find any easier way, perhaps CCheckListBox does the same thing internally? anyway thanks for the answer.