# How to obtain checked items form listview - Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a custom adapter that consists of a checkbox and some textviews. I need a way to know/obtain the items that have been selected using the checkboxes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You custom adaptor is most likely using a list of a data model. You just add a boolean field to the data model. Following existing tutorials, in this one as an example look closely at `boolean selected = false;` in class `Country`

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be useful:

[How to make checkboxes in a list view control tri-state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633383/how-to-make-checkboxes-in-a-list-view-control-tri-state)